# Query on Linked Tables

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me with a query, I've been playing with this for a while and couldn't get the desired result.

Here is a dump of my sample DB:[PHPMyAdmin SQL Dump](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wSwfXSmX)

I would like to achieve a result to be something like:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [r_id] => 1
                [u_id] => 1
                [e_id] => 1
                [r] => r1
                [username] => john
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [r_id] => 1
                [u_id] => 2
                [e_id] => 1
                [r] => r1
                [username] => mark
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [r_id] => 1
                [u_id] => 3
                [e_id] => 1
                [r] => r1
                [username] => andrew
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [r_id] => 
                [u_id] => 
                [e_id] => 1
                [r] => r2
            )

    )
)
```

This is the closest query I can make:[My PHP code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0D61CEX5)

Answer (score 0):

Try using inner joins on your query

```
SELECT 
  tb1.*, tb2.e, tb3.e_id, tb3.r, tb4.r_id, tb4.u_id
FROM 
  tb1
INNER JOIN 
  tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.id
INNER JOIN
  tb3 ON tb1.id = tb3.id
INNER JOIN
  tb4 ON tb1.id = tb4.id
```

After editing the query edit

```
$sack[$rowId][] = $row;
```

To

```
$sack[] = $row;
```

or

```
$sack[$rowId] = $row;
```

Comment: At the bottom part of the question is a link of the code.

Comment: But have you tested it with my query? Could past a link to the code where you are using the query

Comment: Yes I tested your query. I just replaced my query with the one you gave and this is the result : [Array Result](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kSLzz39Y)

Comment: In $sack[$rowId][] = $row; remove [$rowId].

Comment: It doesn't really work. [Result](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LPyrgDPt) However, it seems like the 1 data is removed from the array.

Comment: Could you edit your question and specify what kind of result your want. Because it is not really clear. This query looks like it works for you

Comment: The question is really what I want to pursue.  My query just missed the link between tb4 and tb1 which I can't seem to figure out how.  Your query however links tb4 and tb1 and tb4 and tb3 but it filters out the data inside tb3 that has no link to tb4

Comment: Then you could use tb3 as a starting point to joint the tables. It has more rows so you could LEFT JOIN the tables

Comment: Thank you GusDB. I started my query from tb3 and everything was ok.

Answer (score 0):

@GusDB your hint to start at TB3 was the key, so here's the answer

```
select * from tb3 
    left join tb4 on tb3.id=tb4.r_id
    left join tb1 on tb4.u_id=tb1.id
```

The PHP Code

```
<?php

$sql = mysqli_query($con, '
            select * from tb3 
                left join tb4 on tb3.id=tb4.r_id
                left join tb1 on tb4.u_id=tb1.id
');

if (!$sql) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}

$sack = Array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
   $sack[$row['r_id']][] = $row;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($sack);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```